# Has any new Conan the Barbarian fiction been published since 2003?

Tags: conan

The last Conan novel that I'm aware of is *Conan of Venarium* by Harry Turtledove (2003).
Not including comics and such, have any Conan stories been published since then?

Answer (score 9):

## Yes and No

Between 2005 and 2006, a new series of nine Conan novels were published, under the collective name ***Age of Conan***.  They are divided into three trilogies:

- *Legends of Kern* (by L.L. Coleman)
- *A Soldier's Quest* (by R.A. Knaak)
- *Marauders* (by J. Mariotte)

These novels tie into the online role-playing game of the same name, *Age of Conan*.

It should be noted that none of these novels features Conan directly — they are simply set in the Conan the Barbarian universe and make occasional references to him — and so in that sense, *Conan of Venarium* is the most recent novel to feature the character of Conan.

Answer (score 7):

The [execrable 2011 film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conan_the_Barbarian_(2011_film)) spawned an equally execrable [novelisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conan_the_Barbarian_(2011_novel)) written by Michael A. Stackpole.

Please note that there is an error on the front cover where it states that the film is ['Now a Major Motion Picture'](https://www.quora.com/Whats-it-like-to-have-your-film-flop-at-the-box-office).

[image]

Comment: Does [Cohen the Barbarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Pratchett%27s_The_Colour_of_Magic) count?

Comment: @DeerHunter - No more than Herenna the henna-haired harridan counts as a Red Sonja substitute...

Comment: the link to a Quora article was quite powerful IMO (really made you feel, really made you understand, and was concise/well-written)

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith - Actually, it made me kinda sad. Anyone with half a brain can see that the film is gonna flop and flop hard. The fact that they justify it by saying "*well, we were too close and couldn't see how badly it sucked*" is really no excuse.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith - Heck, if only his film had been as well written as his excuses why it sucked so bad, maybe it wouldn't have sucked so bad.